# Passing file contents as method arguments (E.g. String)

Tags: java, apache-commons, java-io

I am working on a library which intakes File as `InputStreamReader`

```
Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("inputFile"),"UTF-8");

instances.addThruPipe(new CsvIterator(fileReader, Pattern.compile("^(\\S*)[\\s,]*(\\S*)[\\s,]*(.*)$"), 3, 2, 1));
```

I have another method which creates the data within the file "inputFile" (a tab separated one).

Is is possible to completely get rid of the physical file creation process and pass the file as arguments?

```
String source = "This is the source of my input stream";
InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(source, "UTF-8");
```

If I could do with the above method, How do I take care of the '\t' and '\n' when creating such string?

Comment: How much data you will be creating using the method? Can't you reuse the data already created in an earlier file?

Comment: The `inputFile` has around 500 lines

Answer (score 2):

Your are saving a String source to the file so why not pass the String directly rather than creating the file and passing the file

Comment: How do we take care of tabs and new lines when we pass the argument as string.

Comment: String will be pass as it is saved like  String a = "ginger     apple" will be pass as "ginger     apple"

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making your API take `Reader` as its input parameter.

Now it's the the caller's responsibility to create a `Reader`  - it could be a `FileReader`, an `InputStreamReader` - your library does not need to care.

Your library can continue to build a `CsvIterator` from the `Reader` just as it currently does.

For testing, you can pass it a `StringReader`. In production code, the caller can make a `Reader` from a file, a socket, stdin -- whatever it likes.